# usr/bin/cleos no such file or directory

Tags: cleos, dapp, account-creation

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I am trying to deploy a smart contract, following a Steemit post but I am getting an error that I don't really understand.

I have run nodeos according to the the [Eos developer forum](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/getting-the-software).

In terminal:

```
$ keosd &
  nodeos -e -p eosio \
--plugin eosio::producer_plugin \
--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin \
--plugin eosio::http_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_plugin \
--plugin eosio::history_api_plugin \
--data-dir CONTRACTS_DIR/eosio/data \
--config-dir CONTRACTS_DIR/eosio/config \
--access-control-allow-origin='*' \
--contracts-console \
--http-validate-host=false \
--verbose-http-errors \
--filter-on='*' >> nodeos.log 2>&1 &
```

It works fine. I then successfully created an account using public key.

The problem is that cleos is not usable anymore after I created an account.

I am following a Steemit post as I mentioned above, and it asks me to create another account using the same public key.

I'm now getting the following error everytime use a cleos command:

```
usr/bin/cleos no such file or directory
```

Cleos worked fine just perfectly before I created an account, why is this happening?

Comment: Could you add the full command that's producing the error & link to the Steemit tutorial you are referencing?

Comment: @DonPeat https://steemit.com/devs/@eos-asia/eos-smart-contracts-part-1-getting-started-ping-equivalent-in-eos
This is the post I am referencing. The error is occurred when I try to create another account with the same public key, in the "Interacting with ping" section.
I will try it again soon enough, I will keep it posted.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at where cleos is installed? 
Run:  which cleos to see if cleos path is different. Also noticed your output shows 'usr/bin/cleos' as the path, it should be '/usr/bin/cleos'.  You can run:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/cleos
```

to see if cleos is there. Or use the 'which cleos' command or if you want to find it manually run:

```
cd /
find . -type f -name "cleos" -ls
```

You have cleos, just need to know where it is and then you can access it from command line as:

```
/path/to/cleos
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$ which cleos
```

to tell its location. 
May be in

> /usr/local/bin/cleos

or

> /usr/bin/cleos